# Weird error when moving cells and then loading their properties

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a really weird glitch when moving rows of cells and then accessing their properties. It's honestly too hard to explain so I recorded the glitch happening on the iOS simulator. I am not using storyboards.

Here is the video:
[iPhone Glitch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeNIXW7oTM8&feature=youtu.be)

Here is some relevant code:

TableViewController.m:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    NSString *detailText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval]];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f]];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = turquoiseColor;
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:detailText];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12]];
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:16]];

    if([indexPath section] == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];
    }
    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Tasks *task = [[Tasks alloc]init];
    task.taskName = [[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName];
    task.timeInterval = [[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval];
    task.dateCreated = [[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] dateCreated];
    DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    [dvc setTestTask:task];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{
   Tasks *t = [[Tasks alloc]init];
    if (sourceIndexPath.row > destinationIndexPath.row) {
        [taskArray insertObject:t atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        [taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row + 1)];
    }
    else if (sourceIndexPath.row < destinationIndexPath.row) {
        [taskArray insertObject:t atIndex:(destinationIndexPath.row + 1)];
        [taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row)];
    }
}
```

DetailViewController.h (the cells' properties)

```
@class Tasks;

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLeft;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Tasks *testTask;
@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_timeLeft setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeue" size:25]];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [testTask timeInterval]];
    [_timerLabel setText:time];
    [_timerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeue" size:60]];
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:[testTask taskName]];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [testTask setTaskName:[testTask taskName]];
    [testTask setTimeInterval:[testTask timeInterval]];

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is not related to Xcode.

Comment: I hope that taskArray is a NSMutableArray, so you simply could use `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting an empty `Tasks` object whenever the user moves a row. Instead, try this to move items in your data source array:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    Tasks *taskToMove = [taskArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [taskArray insertObject:taskToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

I think the reason why you are only seeing the error after you push a view controller and pop it is that when the user moves a row, the row doesn't reload. If it had reloaded, you would have seen the glitch then.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you were right, i should have used the task at the sourceindexpath row instead of just an empty one. silly mistake. THANKS :)